# PHP.ini max_execution_time setting not being honoured by EE

Tags: php, server, php.ini

I've being trying to increase the `max_execution_time` php variable for an EE site (EE 2.6.1, FastCGI on php 5.4.44, running on SiteGround's Managed Cloud hosting with cPanel) but it's not updating the local value, currently only 300. Only the global value changes to 800.

This is what I see in EE's CP > Tools > Utilities > PHP Info

[image: EE CP PHP Info]

Whereas another php info file that sits in the webroot for the site shows this

[image: PHP Info in webroot directory]

Using cPanel's PHP Variable Manager, I've increased the `memory_limit` and `max_input_vars` without issue: both the local and global values change.

My host's support say that it's an EE "thing". But I've never come across anything of the sort. How do I get the `max_execution_time` already set as a global value to be honoured by EE?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently to resolve this you have to hack the `/system/expressionengine/libraries/Core.php` file.

From

```
@set_time_limit((REQ == 'CP') ? 300 : 90);
```

to

```
@set_time_limit((REQ == 'CP') ? 800 : 90);
```

Not pretty nor advisable.

Answer (score 1):

Roll this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

into your main index.php file, and set your `max_execution_time` via that method. It only sets it for that script execution, so you may have to put it in your `system` index.php file as well, depending on your use case.

This really isn't an EE thing (unless someone manually set it like how I'm suggesting you fix it), so your host is being incompetent.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '800');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this made no difference.